# Check Using JSTL/Spring-MVC tag regarding Spring Binding Error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to find a way by which i can check if there is any binding error and based on them i want to show some messages to the user in Spring-MVC. i know one way of this like

```
<spring:hasBindErrors name="userName">

</spring:hasBindErrors>
```

but this seems to be with respect to a specific filed of my form, what i want is to check if there is any binding error at all for the current input form or not?
i have also experience of Struts2 and they have a very convient method `hasError()` which allow a developer to see if there is any error at all for the input fields.

Is there such method defined for Spring-MVC validation or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an expert of Spring-MVC as i have used it very rarely but if i am correct all you want an equivalent of `bindingResult.hasErrors()` and if i am correct all you need to use

`hasBindErrors` tag. For more details refer to the doc

- [hasBindErrors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/apds04.html)

Hope this might help you